# How to setup PHP Server for ReactJS Tutorial

Tags: php, git, bash, shell

I am intending to work through the ReactJS tutorial (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) but am unable to figure out how to setup the server.

I want to run the `php server.php` command as per the github README (https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/#to-use).

Having done very little command line coding, I wanted to run this from Git Shell which I have installed on my Windows 7 system which also includes WAMP.

When I run command `php server.php` in git shell, I get error:

> Bash: php: command not found

Now this seems to be occuring because I have not initialized the Git Shell to recognize this command, alas, I can't seem to find a coherent answer throughout my searches on how to do this.

My real question is, how/where do I run that code (`php server.php`) to begin working with reactJS as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the PHP executable in your Windows `PATH` variable.

Once this is the case, you should be able to run PHP scripts as described in the tutorial.